# How to get instance ID with PHP

Tags: php, resources, object, instance, var-dump

I'm looking for a way to get the instance ID of a given object / resource with PHP, the same way var_dump() does:

```
var_dump(curl_init()); // resource #1 of type curl
var_dump(curl_init()); // resource #2 of type curl
```

How can I get the instance count without calling var_dump()? Is it possible?

Comment: what for?  it makes little sense.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Convert it to an int to get the resource ID:

```
$resource= curl_init();
var_dump($resource);
var_dump(intval($resource));
```

Comment: He mentioned without using `var_dump` ;)

Comment: So simple... Thanks pygorex1!

Comment: This is actually a very good solution. You could also just do 
(int) $resource

Comment: or, equivalently: `(int)$resource`. But the manual says that technically this conversion is undefined.

Comment: You don't happen to have a solution for http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2872366/get-instance-id-of-an-object-in-php, don't you? :)

Answer (score 6):

Before PHP 8.0:

```
(int) curl_init();
```

PHP 8.0+:

```
spl_object_id(curl_init());
```

Across versions:

```
$handle = curl_init();
is_object($handle) ? spl_object_id($hadle) : (int) $handle;
// unset($handle);
```

Comment: because I initially thought you really need to get the exact string

"resource(x) of type Y" - but after I read your question again I figured you really only want the integer value without the clutter ;-)

Comment: In php8, curl_init() no longer returns a resource, it returns an instance of CurlHandle

Answer (score 3):

This is a very interesting question... I would be interested to see what you would use this for... but here is one way...

```
$ch = curl_init();
preg_match("#\d+#", (string) $ch, $matches);
$resourceIdOne = end($matches);

$ch2 = curl_init();
preg_match("#\d+#", (string) $ch2, $matches);
$resourceIdTwo = end($matches);
```

compare: https://stackoverflow.com/a/68303184/367456

Comment: I won't be using this for anything out of the normal, I was thinking in replacing the var_dump() for a more informative / readable function but I suppose it can be used in a clever registry pattern as well.

Answer (score 2):

In PHP8 many functions return now a class instance instead of a resource:

```
$resource = curl_init();
$id = PHP_MAJOR_VERSION >= 8 ? spl_object_id($resource) : (int)$resource;
```

or

```
$id = is_resource($resource) ? (int)$resource : spl_object_id($resource);
```

Comment: This works best right now at this date if any code has a resource cast to an int. FYI your code is missing the $ in front of resource variable.

Answer (score 1):

Convert resource to id with `sprintf()`

```
$resource = curl_init();
$id = sprintf('%x', $resource);

// mimic var_dump();
$type = get_resource_type($resource);
echo "resource({$id}) of type ({$type})\n";
```

Answer (score 0):

```
function get_resource_id($resource) {
    if (!is_resource($resource))
        return false;

    return array_pop(explode('#', (string)$resource));
}
```