# Get Instance ID of an Object in PHP

Tags: php, class, object, resources, instance

I've learn a while ago on StackOverflow that [we can get the "instance ID" of any resource](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1853622/how-to-get-instance-id-with-php), for instance:

```
var_dump(intval(curl_init()));  // int(2)
var_dump(intval(finfo_open())); // int(3)
var_dump(intval(curl_init()));  // int(4)
var_dump(intval(finfo_open())); // int(5)
var_dump(intval(curl_init()));  // int(6)
```

I need something similar but applied to classes:

```
class foo {
    public function __construct() {
        ob_start();
        var_dump($this); // object(foo)#INSTANCE_ID (0) { }
        echo preg_replace('~.+#(\d+).+~s', '$1', ob_get_clean());
    }
}

$foo = new foo();  // 1
$foo2 = new foo(); // 2
```

The above works but I was hoping for a faster solution or, at least, one that didn't involve output buffers. Please note that this won't necessarily be used within the constructor or even inside the class itself!

<del>`spl_object_hash()` is not what I'm looking for because the two objects produce identical hashes</del>

The question previously contained an incorrect example of `spl_object_hash` output; ensuring that both objects exist at the same time produces hashes which are subtly different:

```
var_dump(spl_object_hash($foo));  // 0000000079e5f3b60000000042b31773
var_dump(spl_object_hash($foo2)); // 0000000079e5f3b50000000042b31773
```

Casting to int like resources doesn't seem to work for objects:

> **Notice:** Object of class foo could not be converted to int.

**Is there a quick way to grab the same output without using object properties**?

Besides `var_dump()`, I've discovered by trial and error that [`debug_zval_dump()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.debug-zval-dump.php) also outputs the object instance, unfortunately it also needs output buffering since it doesn't return the result.

Comment: No, this is NOT the  '"instance ID" of any resource' its the resource id cast to an integer - which is not the same thing at all.

Comment: @symcbean: You seem to have noticed the enclosing quotes... The question is still valid, no reason to downvote.

Comment: How willing would you be to delve into PHP source code and create such a feature? You won't (assuming I understand what you want--to determine if/how many times any given class has been instantiated, without adding code to each constructor) be able to do what you want in PHP.

Comment: @salathe: I don't want to know how many times a given class has been instantiated, I can know that by checking `$GLOBALS`. What I want to know is the instance number of any given object, which is slightly different. Anyway, I rather not modify the PHP source code, since I won't have that option everywhere.

Comment: @Alix: Could you help us clarify why you need the "instance ID" (which I don't think exist in php)?. Imo, a static counter should work as well. As in:
class Foo{ private static $instances = 0;  public function __construct(){ self::$instances++;} }

Comment: @Martin: Well, PHP "knows" it otherwise it wouldn't show up on `var_dump()` however I also believe there is no easy way to get it. Regarding the clarification it's rather long to post here, but I've spent several hours studying it and believe me when I say that this it's the only thing that works in my scenario. The solution you provided just acts like a counter (*how many objects of class exists* vs *"when" was this class instantiated*), and like I said in my question I'm looking for a solution that doesn't involve object properties.

Comment: @Alix: Ok, just a heads up regarding using that a a unique object id which I stumbled upon: http://www.mail-archive.com/internals@lists.php.net/msg28779.html

Comment: @Martin: Great find, thanks! This guy has exactly the same need as I do: http://www.mail-archive.com/internals@lists.php.net/msg28773.html. Also Googling for `__toInt() PHP` yields some interesting results, all of them however are custom PHP extensions.

Comment: @Martin: Thanks! This comment http://www.mail-archive.com/internals@lists.php.net/msg28820.html made me double check that `spl_object_hash` actually yields a difference! A very suble one however: `0000000079e5f3b60000000042b31773` and `0000000079e5f3b50000000042b31773`, for instance. This mostly solves my need! :)

Comment: since php 7.2.0 there exists the build-in function spl_object_id: https://www.php.net/manual/de/function.spl-object-id.php

Answer (score 38, accepted):

[`spl_object_hash()`](http://de.php.net/manual/en/function.spl-object-hash.php) could help you out here. It

> returns a unique identifier for the object

which is always the same for a given instance.

**EDIT** after OP comment:

You could implement such a behavior using a static class property, e.g:

```
class MyClass 
{
    private static $_initialized = false;

    public function __construct()
    {
        if (!self::$_initialized) {
            self::$_initialized = true;
            // your run-only-once code 
        }
    }
}
```

But actually this has nothing to with your original question.

Comment: Note, from the `spl_object_hash` documentation: "When an object is destroyed, its hash may be reused for other objects." I have come across this, and this makes it useless for some purposes.

Answer (score 19):

Well, yes, with an extension.

Note that the handles used for objects that were, in the meantime, destroyed, can be reused.

Build with `phpize && ./configure && make && make install`

#### testext.h

```
#ifndef PHP_EXTTEST_H
# define PHP_EXTTEST_H
# ifdef HAVE_CONFIG_H
#  include<config.h>
# endif
# include <php.h>
extern zend_module_entry testext_module_entry;
#define phpext_testext_ptr &testext_module_entry
#endif
```

#### testext.c

```
#include "testext.h"

PHP_FUNCTION(get_object_id)
{
    zval *obj;
    if (zend_parse_parameters(ZEND_NUM_ARGS() TSRMLS_CC, "o", &obj)
            == FAILURE) {
        return;
    }

    RETURN_LONG(Z_OBJ_HANDLE_P(obj));
}

static zend_function_entry ext_functions[] = {
    PHP_FE(get_object_id, NULL)
    {NULL, NULL, NULL, 0, 0}
};

zend_module_entry testext_module_entry = {
    STANDARD_MODULE_HEADER,
    "testext",
    ext_functions, /* Functions */
    NULL, /* MINIT */
    NULL, /* MSHUTDOWN */
    NULL, /* RINIT */
    NULL, /* RSHUTDOWN */
    NULL, /* MINFO */
    NO_VERSION_YET,
    STANDARD_MODULE_PROPERTIES
};

ZEND_GET_MODULE(testext)
```

#### config.m4

```
PHP_ARG_ENABLE(testext,
  [Whether to enable the "testext" extension],
  [  enable-testext         Enable "testext" extension support])

if test $PHP_EXTTEST != "no"; then
  PHP_SUBST(EXTTEST_SHARED_LIBADD)
  PHP_NEW_EXTENSION(testext, testext.c, $ext_shared)
fi
```

#### Test script

```
<?php
$a = new stdclass();
$b = new stdclass();
var_dump(get_object_id($a));
var_dump(get_object_id($b));
```

#### Output

```
int(1)
int(2)
```

Comment: Although this was not the solution I was hoping for I'm gonna upvote it and if no better solution is presented I'm gonna award the bounty to this answer. You didn't have to go to all this trouble, but nice job! :)

Comment: Note that the "object handle" returned here is one of the two pieces of information used by the existing `spl_object_hash` function, as can be seen in its source code here: http://lxr.php.net/xref/PHP_5_6/ext/spl/php_spl.c#785

Answer (score 4):

Alix, your solution in the question was exactly what I needed, but actually breaks when there's an object in an object, returns the last # in the var_dump. I fixed this, made the regex faster, and put it in a nice little function.

```
/**
 * Get global object ID
 * From: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2872366/get-instance-id-of-an-object-in-php
 * By: Alix Axel, non-greedy fix by Nate Ferrero
 */
function get_object_id(&$obj) {
    if(!is_object($obj))
        return false;
    ob_start();
    var_dump($obj);// object(foo)#INSTANCE_ID (0) { }
    preg_match('~^.+?#(\d+)~s', ob_get_clean(), $oid);
    return $oid[1]; 
}
```

Answer (score 4):

As of PHP 7.2 you can use [spl_object_id](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.spl-object-id.php)

```
$id = spl_object_id($object);
$storage[$id] = $object;
```

Comment: Careful:
`**Note:** When an object is destroyed, its id may be reused for other objects.`

Answer (score 3):

Have a look at [`spl_object_hash()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.spl-object-hash.php). Usage example:

```
$id = spl_object_hash($object);
```

Note that you'll need PHP 5 >= 5.2.0 for that to work.

Comment: Sounds to me like you want to use the factory pattern

Comment: @Mark: Unfortunately, I'm pretty sure that's not the case.

Comment: @Alix Axel: This is definetly a flaw in your concept !
Running some code in the constructor only once is against EVERY OOP-Rule, describe your problem very detailled and we can find a solution, but what you're trying to do is nothing more than an UGLY HACK.

Comment: @Tobias: I know that - forget about the constructor, it was only an example. I would like to know the instance ID of an object independently of the scope I'm in (even outside the class).

Comment: @Alix Axel: Tell us the real problem, and we can give you real help. I can doubt there's a real net design pattern or best practice to solve your problem but not as long as you tell us your real problem.

Comment: @Tobias: The real problem is too long to put into a comment and would just add confusion to the question to make things worse it can't be considered as a best practice implementation (and that's okay) since I know what the "best practice" approach would be and I don't want that in this case. Believe me, I've studied the problem well and the only way that would work for me is something that can return a unique id for a given object variable, independently of the scope. An `intval()` like approach would be the best, since it's fast and also counts how many times the object was instantiated.

Answer (score 3):

As long as you implement the base class all the classes you're going to need this from, you can do something like this:

```
class MyBase
{
    protected static $instances = 0;
    private $_instanceId  = null;
    public function getInstanceId()
    {
        return $this->_instanceId;
    }

    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->_instanceId = ++self::$instances;
    }
}

class MyTest extends MyBase
{
    public function Foo()
    {
        /* do something really nifty */
    }
}

$a = new MyBase();
$b = new MyBase();

$c = new MyTest();
$d = new MyTest();


printf("%d (should be 1) \n", $a->getInstanceId());
printf("%d (should be 2) \n", $b->getInstanceId());
printf("%d (should be 3) \n", $c->getInstanceId());
printf("%d (should be 4) \n", $d->getInstanceId());
```

The output would be:

```
1 (should be 1) 
2 (should be 2) 
3 (should be 3) 
4 (should be 4)
```

Answer (score 2):

What you're trying to do, is actually [Aspect-Oriented Programming](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Aspect-oriented_programming) (AOP).

There are at least a couple of frameworks available for AOP in PHP at this point:

- [seasar](http://www.seasar.org/en/php5/index.html) (formerly PHPaspect) is a larger framework integrating with Eclipse - the screenshot shows you a little code snippet that answers your question, weaving some code around a particular new statement throughout a project.
- [php-aop](http://code.google.com/p/php-aop/) is a lightweight framework for AOP.
- [typo3](http://flow3.typo3.org/documentation/manuals/flow3/flow3.aopframework/) has an AOP framework built in.

This may be overkill for your needs, but you may find that exploring the kind of thinking behind ideas like these will lead you down the rabbit hole, and teach you new ways to think about software development in general - AOP is a powerful concept, allowing you to program in terms of strategies and concerns, or "aspects".

Languages like PHP were designed to solve *programming* tasks - the concept of AOP was designed to solve *a programmers'* task. When normally you would need to think about how to ensure that a particular concern gets fulfilled every time in your code base, you can think of this as simply an "aspect" of how you're programming, implement it in those terms directly, and count on your concerns to be implemented every time.

It requires less discipline, and you can focus on solving the practical programming tasks rather than trying to architect your way through high-level structural code requirements.

Comment: Thanks, I'll definitely take a look at it ASAP. Can't find any screenshots for seasar though.

Comment: Yeah, I don't think there is one, sorry - I meant to point you to this tool:

http://code.google.com/p/apdt/

This one has integration with Eclipse too, and that must have been the screenshot I had in my mind.

Answer (score 1):

I don't have the PECL runkit enabled to test this, but this may allow you to remove the constructor code from the class definition after the first time that an instance of the class has been created.

Whether you can remove the constructor from within the constructor would be an interesting experiment.

Comment: I understand you're trying to answer what has been discussed in previous comments but I just want to get the instance ID number of an object, that's my only goal. Nice rep by the way (2^11)! :)

Comment: @AlixAxel Use PHP 7.2 with `get_instance_id()`. By the definition it gets you the instance ID. Please accept the answer to the question that fits, there is one about `spl_object_hash()` which is not the instance ID but hash and if I read your comment right you should switch the answer selection. Please do conformance testing beforehand. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

This is a bit late to the party but I didn't see this answer and just recently implemented something similar for a debugging class ( to handle circular references).  As you guys may or may not know the normal printing functions such as `var_export`, have limited or no circular reference support.

As noted the spl_object_hash is unique per instance, the problem I had with it is that it is ugly.  Not really suited to printing for my debugger as it's something like this `000000006ac56bae0000000044fda36f` which can be hard to compare to say this `000000006ac56bae0000000044fda35f`.  So like the OP stated what I wanted was just a number of the instance ( I only really needed this on a per class basis ).

Therefor the simple solution for me was to do the following.

```
    $class = get_class( $input );
    $hash = spl_object_hash( $input );
    if( !isset( $objInstances[ $class ] )){
        $objInstances[ $class ] = array();
    }

    $output = 'object(%s) #%s (%s){%s}'; //class, instance, prop_count, props
    if( false === ( $index = array_search($hash, $objInstances[ $class ] ) ) ){
        $index = count($objInstances[ $class ]); //set init index for instance
        $objInstances[ $class ][] = $hash;
        // .... debugging code
        $output = 'debugging result.', //sprintf 
    }else{
        $output = sprintf( $output, $class, $index, 0, '#_CIRCULAR_REFRENCE_#');
    }
```

Obviously the debugging code is way more complex, but the essential thing here is that by tracking the class and spl hash in `$objInstances` I can easily assign my own instance numbers outside of the class.  This means I don't need some ugly hack ( that affects the class's code ) to get a reference number. Also, I don't need to display the "ugly" spl hash.  Anyway my full code for this outputs something like this.

```
$obj = new TestObj();
$obj1 = new TestObj();

$obj->setProProp($obj1);
$obj1->setProProp($obj); //create a circular reference 

object(TestObj) #0 (7){
    ["SOME_CONST":const] => string(10) 'some_const',
    ["SOMEOTHER_CONST":const] => string(16) 'some_other_const',
    ["SOME_STATIC":public static] => string(6) 'static',
    ["_PRO_STATIC":protected static] => string(10) 'pro_static',
    ["someProp":public] => string(8) 'someProp',
    ["_pro_prop":protected] => object(TestObj) #1 (7){
        ["SOME_CONST":const] => string(10) 'some_const',
        ["SOMEOTHER_CONST":const] => string(16) 'some_other_const',
        ["SOME_STATIC":public static] => string(6) 'static',
        ["_PRO_STATIC":protected static] => string(10) 'pro_static',
        ["someProp":public] => string(8) 'someProp',
        ["_pro_prop":protected] => object(TestObj) #0 (0){#_CIRCULAR_REFRENCE_#},
        ["_proProp":protected] => string(7) 'proProp'
    },
    ["_proProp":protected] => string(7) 'proProp'
}
```

As you can see it's very easy to see where `object(TestObj) #0 (0){#_CIRCULAR_REFRENCE_#}` came from now.  I wanted to keep this debugging code as close to the native `var_dump`
which outputs this.

```
object(TestObj)#7 (3) {
  ["someProp"]=> string(8) "someProp"
  ["_pro_prop":protected]=> object(TestObj)#10 (3) {
    ["someProp"]=> string(8) "someProp"
    ["_pro_prop":protected]=> *RECURSION*
    ["_proProp":protected]=> string(7) "proProp"
  }
  ["_proProp":protected]=> string(7) "proProp"
}
```

The difference here is I needed the return as a string, not output to the browser.  I also wanted to be able to show class constants, static properties, and private properties ( with flags to change what the debugger outputs, and the depth limit). And, I wanted a bit more information as to what the circular reference was instead of just `*RECURSION*` which doesn't tell me anything.

Hope it helps someone in the future.

Here is the full code for my Debug class, you can find this used about line #300

https://github.com/ArtisticPhoenix/Evo/blob/master/Evo/Debug.php

Comment: The link to your own repo is dead, please update it.

Answer (score 0):

If you don't want to use output buffering... perhaps use [`var_export`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.var-export.php) instead of `var_dump`?

Comment: `var_export()` will *not* include the instance ID like `var_dump()` does.