# PHP get index of object

Tags: php, oop, object

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Get Instance ID of an Object in PHP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2872366/get-instance-id-of-an-object-in-php)

I'm new to OOP and I have an object. If I:

```
var_dump($obj);
```

I get:

```
object(stdClass)[55]
    public 'date' => int 1295297161
    public 'id' => int 11
```

How can I retrieve the "55"?

Comment: For what do you need that 'index'? It's not an array key, it's more like internal identifier.

Comment: The only way to get that 55 value is to "parse" the output from the var_dump()... but there is no valid reason why you should need this information. Any reason you might have can probably better be implemented using different methods (e.g. an array of objects)

Comment: Related: [Get Instance ID of an Object in PHP](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2872366/get-instance-id-of-an-object-in-php)

Answer (score 1):

As others have mentioned you can't read it, without parsing the output of `var_dump`. But if all you are looking for is a way to uniquely identify an object, then you should use [`spl_object_hash`](http://php.net/spl_object_hash).